# How to remove the first node from a range using detach?

Tags: javascript, range, detach

How can I remove the *window.getSelection().anchorNode* from a range?

I have tried the following...

```
window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).detach(window.getSelection().anchorNode);
```

...and since the method is poorly documented...

```
window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).detach.window.getSelection().anchorNode;
```

Comment: is this jQuery's detach method?

Comment: Frameworks aren't acceptable.

Comment: I have figured out the answer however the site is refusing to let me answer it for a few hours. I'll post the answer once the site lifts the restriction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this does not resolve the problem at hand (which I have not mentioned) this does seem to remove the node from the range...

```
alert(window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode.nodevalue);

for (var k=0;k<window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer.childNodes.length;k++)
{
 if (window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer.childNodes[k].isSameNode(window.getSelection().anchorNode))
 {
  window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).detach(window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer.childNodes[k]);
  break;
 }
}

alert(window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode.nodeName);
```

Comment: `detach()` does not have anything to do with removing nodes from the range, except in the sense that after calling it the range has no nodes and is unusable. Did you read my answer?

Answer (score 0):

The [`detach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range.detach) method of `Range` is only used to dispose of a range when you're done with it. It has no impact on the document from which the range came.

If you want to remove the range's start container node from the range, you can do

```
range.setStartAfter(range.startContainer);
```